# Retain nullable designation on object properties when extracting property

Tags: typescript

I am having trouble retaining the nullable designation on object properties.

```
type Dog = {
  age: number | null;
}

type DogAge = Dog['age'];
type DogAge1 = Pick<Dog, 'age'>;
```

The type of DogAge and DogAge1 are `number` and `{age: number;}` respectively instead of `number | null`.

I can do `type DogAge = Dog['age'] | null;` but that seems redundant.

Comment: Sounds like you don't have enabled `strictNullChecks`? Your example works in the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAIg9gcygXigbwLACgpQIYIQBcUAdgK4C2ARhAE5QA+Z5ANqwNzYC+22okWIgCChFEIQBtAOQEI0gLpcsA6PASiIARnEAFAJYBjANYAedQBooswtIB8HIA)

Comment: Ah that was it thanks. Weird that isn't enabled by default.